# twitter Bootstrap sidebar and content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap to develop an app,

One Sub-header,One sidebar and main content. Following is the test.

example here photoshop ![example][1]

I would like to reproduce the example, but the result and not good

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sub-header">subheader???</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span9" id="file">
          <ol class="group" id="alist">
            <li>
              <div class="filename">
                  <i class="icon-ban-circle"></i>
                  <span> 3 files .</span>
              </div>
              <div class="alist">
                  <span class="info">28 minutes ago</span>
              </div>
           </li>
        </ol>
     </div>
    <div class="span3" id="sidebar">
    <li>
        <div class="filename2">
           <i class="icon-ban-circle"></i><span> INFO .</span>
        </div>
    </li>
      <div class="row-fluid" >
        <div class="span12 center-block">
    <li>
        <div class="filename">
           <i class="icon-ban-circle"></i><span> INFO .</span>
        </div>
    </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

test online: http://jsfiddle.net/q2CBj/

so how to reproduce a good **Sub-header** and **content** as in the image with twitter bootstrap ???

sorry for my english.

Thnak you for futur reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of example layouts on [bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples), take a look at them.

First of all, what have you even tried? I would suggest that you try a themeroller for bootstrap, http://bootswatchr.com/ or http://www.bootstrapthemeroller.com/ , where you can easily create what you want.

Comment: Thank you Christian, it's perfect for sidebar & content.